# problems with $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey i've started learning angularJS and i'm quite new to it so i gues my best bet is to ask someone.

So my $routeProvider is not routing me to anything really when i run it it wont load any partials when i see the console a get this message Error:[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module collectify due to: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute.

app.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="routing.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/controllers/categoryController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/controllers/itemController.js"></script>

    <!-- Directives -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/directives/itemDecoratorDirective.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/services/itemProvider.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="collectify">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app=angular.module('collectify',['ngRoute']);
```

routing.js

```
'use strict';
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/items/',{
                controller:'itemList',
                templateUrl:'views/item/list.html'
            })
  }]);
```

itemController.js

```
'use strict';
app
    .controller('itemIndex',function($scope){

    })
    .controller('itemList', function($scope,itemProvider){
        $scope.items=itemProvider.getItems();
    })
    .controller('itemCreate',function($scope){
        $scope.test="toto";
    })
    .controller('itemRemove',function($scope){

    })
;
```

my service itemProvider.js

```
'use strict';
var items=[{'libelle':'Transporteur','id_category':1},  {'libelle':'Taken','id_category':1},{'libelle':'Ahmed','id_category':2},    {'libelle':'Muslim','id_category':2} ]

app.service('itemProvider',function(){  this.getItems=function(){       return items;   } })
```

my directive itemDecoratorDirective.js

```
'use strict';
app.directive('decorateItem',function(){
    return{
        template:'Le film "{{item.libelle}}" dont la categorie est {{item.id_category}}'
    }
})
```

my view list.html

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <p decorate-item></p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the script `angular-route.js` is loaded?

Comment: yes the file is loaded correctly

Comment: The problem should be the `angular-route.js` didn't be loaded correctly. Do check it again.

Comment: i checked again the file is loaded correctly i took a picture when the files are loaded [link]http://tinyurl.com/ncfql9s